# How to slowly move header while user scrolls the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve the effect that is used on this Header on this example website:

http://anchorage-theme.pixelunion.net/

You will notice that as you scroll the page, the header slowly moves upward until it disappears from view. I want to achieve this same effect. I believe it will need some JS and CSS positioning but still have no clue how to achieve this. Is this done with parallax scrolling?

Would appreciate if someone could give me a quick example of the code used to do this with a   element. So I can then use it on my own site.

Cheers.

Comment: Suggestion: Do a view source of the site you showed in your example above to reveal the code behind the effect.

Comment: It seems pretty confusing, already had a look at the source :S @Dexter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the $(window).scroll(function () {...}) is the one you need here

$(document).scrollTop() is the amount of scrolled distance from the top

Comment: the $(window).scroll event fires when the user scrolls the page. So relating to the amount of scroll the user has done and to the header's properties (i'm not very sure here) you decrease the height of the header acordingly.  this is an example $(window).scroll(function () {
$('#navigation').css('top', $(document).scrollTop());
});

Comment: Any chance you can do a quick jsfiddle so I can see some example code in action ? @Rzv

Comment: It's not too difficult. @Rzv.im is correct. Depending how far you scroll from the top, you reduce the height of the header. `headerheight = scrollTop < MIN_HEIGHT ? MIN_HEIGHT : headerheight - scrollTop;` where `MIN_HEIGHT` is a constant that represents how skinny you want the header to look when scrolled beyond the threshhold.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > x){  // x should be from where you want this to happen from top//
    //make CSS changes here
  } 
  else{
    //back to default styles

  }
});
```

Comment: I believe I could use this but I want it to transition as the user scrolls. In your example say if i set 'x' to 200. as soon as the user reached 201 the change would instantly happen? @SVS